# Calculate average (grade) using HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, average

Hey there I'm trying to calculate average from data in Map.

First in a code there is class Student in which a... well a student is created with parameters as follow:
String firstName, String lastName, int registerDiaryNumber.

Also methods equals, hashCode and toString are Overridden.

Then the class Grade is created and it takes 8 int as parameter (8 grades total)

Finally in main there is this piece of code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

Student student1 = new Student("Terry", "Pratchett", 2);
Student student2 = new Student("Arashi", "Ryuuno", 3);
Student student3 = new Student("Nobunaga", "Oda", 4); 
Student student4 = new Student("Pheonix", "Wright", 5);
Student student5 = new Student("Ainz", "Gown", 1);

Grades student1Math = new Grades(4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3);
Grades student2Math = new Grades(5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4);
Grades student3Math = new Grades(3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2);
Grades student4Math = new Grades(5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5);
Grades student5Math = new Grades(4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5);

Map<Student, Grades> mathGrades = new HashMap<>();
mathGrades.put(student1, student1Math);
mathGrades.put(student2, student2Math);
mathGrades.put(student3, student3Math);
mathGrades.put(student4, student4Math);
mathGrades.put(student5, student5Math);

for (Map.Entry<Student, Grades> entry : mathGrades.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("Number " + entry.getKey() +" got grades as follow:" +entry.getValue());
    System.out.println("Student average grade is: ");
    }
}
```

And thats where I stuck - I have no idea how to calculate average from given grades I tried putting methods in class grade but it did not work.
If you want to check the whole code then please check the link below (This is an assignment from JAVA bootcamp and it states "using HashMap create a program that will store Students (personal) data and their grades. Program **has to** show average grade of every student."
The average can be either an int or double (rounded).

https://kodilla.com/pl/project-java/173235#

Comment: It is unusual that `Grades` is not a field in the class `Student` but exists loose. However, it would be helpful to answer your question  if you could include the classes of `Grades` and `Student` in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change the constructor of `Grade` class that takes a `List` of Integers for example.

The solution of the problem will be as simple as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student1 = new Student("Terry", "Pratchett", 2);
    Student student2 = new Student("Arashi", "Ryuuno", 3);
    Student student3 = new Student("Nobunaga", "Oda", 4);
    Student student4 = new Student("Pheonix", "Wright", 5);
    Student student5 = new Student("Ainz", "Gown", 1);

    // A static initialization of a list of integers
    Grades student1Math = new Grades(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(5);
        add(6);
        add(5); // add more here...
    }});
    Grades student2Math = new Grades(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(5);
        add(6);
        add(5);
    }});
    Grades student3Math = new Grades(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(3);
        add(3);
        add(5);
    }});
    Grades student4Math = new Grades(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(5);
        add(4);
        add(5);
    }});
    Grades student5Math = new Grades(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(4);
        add(5);
        add(5);
    }};

    Map<Student, Grades> mathGrades = new HashMap<>();
    mathGrades.put(student1, student1Math);
    mathGrades.put(student2, student2Math);
    mathGrades.put(student3, student3Math);
    mathGrades.put(student4, student4Math);
    mathGrades.put(student5, student5Math);

    for (Map.Entry<Student, Grades> entry : mathGrades.entrySet()){
        double currentStudentAvgSum = 0.0;
        
        List<Integer> studentGrades = mathGrades.get(entry.getKey());
        for(Dobule currentGrade : studentGrades){
            currentStudentAvgSum + = currentGrade;
        }
        double currentStudentAvg = currentStudentAvgSum / studentGrades.size();
        
        System.out.println("Student average grade is: " + currentStudentAvg);
    }
}
```

And the for loop calculates average scores per student.

Answer (score 0):

below is the JAVA code which might be helpful to this question.

This is Student class in another java file.

```
package StudentGradeTracker;

public class Student {

private int eng, maths, sci;

public Student(int eng, int maths, int sci) {
    this.eng = eng;
    this.maths = maths;
    this.sci = sci;
}

public Student() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + eng + ", " + maths + ", " + sci + "]";
}

public int getEng() {
    return eng;
}

public void setEng(int eng) {
    this.eng = eng;
}

public int getMaths() {
    return maths;
}

public void setMaths(int maths) {
    this.maths = maths;
}

public int getSci() {
    return sci;
}

public void setSci(int sci) {
    this.sci = sci;
}

}
```

This is MainClass which is another java file.

```
package StudentGradeTracker;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    HashMap<String, Student> hm = new HashMap<>();
    
    hm.put("Hassan", new Student(70, 70, 70));
    hm.put("Abrar", new Student(35,45,55));
    hm.put("Tausif", new Student(65,35,50));
    
    for (String string : hm.keySet()) {
        calculateAverage(hm.get(string), hm, string);
    }
    
}

static void calculateAverage(Student student, HashMap<String, Student> 
hm1, String key)
{
    int sum = 0;
    
    sum = sum + student.getEng() + student.getMaths() + student.getSci();
    
    double avg = (double) sum / hm1.size();
    
    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Marks : " + hm1.get(key) + " Percentage : " + avg + calculateGrade(avg));
    
}

static String calculateGrade(double avg){
    char result, grade;
    
    if(avg > 55.0 && avg <= 70.0){
        result = 'P';
        grade = 'A';
    }
    else if(avg > 45.0 && avg <= 55.0){
        result = 'P';
        grade = 'B';
    }
    else if(avg > 33.0 && avg <= 45.0){
        result = 'P';
        grade = 'C';
    }
    else{
        result = 'F';
        grade = ' ';
    }
    
    return " Result : " + result + " Grade : " + grade;
}
}
```

**OUTPUT:

Key : Abrar Marks : [35, 45, 55] Percentage : 45.0 Result : P Grade : C

Key : Tausif Marks : [65, 35, 50] Percentage : 50.0 Result : P Grade : B

Key : Hassan Marks : [70, 70, 70] Percentage : 70.0 Result : P Grade : A**

Comment: Your code seems unrelated to the code in the question, even though it correctly calculates the average of a set of numbers. The OP is basically asking how to calculate the average of a set of numbers and that is already present in the accepted answer, so what does your answer provide that does not appear in the accepted answer? As far as I am aware, there is only one way to calculate an average and therefore, in my opinion, your answer is essentially a repeat of the accepted answer. Or have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: Here, my code is related to question. Here question is to make grade calculator using hashmap in Java and my code is related to it.